# Can I call multiple IOCTL's at the same time? (Windows Driver)

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I have searched widely, I am writing a network filter and I am putting my registry filter in the same driver. Can I call multiple IOCTL's of the same driver at the same time? Would it be better if I separated my network filter and registry filter?

Answer (score 0):

Open the device using  FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

Then, when sending the IOCTL, use the Overlapped argument. Then the call will return immediately (async) and you can either wait (using WaitForSingleObject), call more things, or do whatever. Beware that the way the data is returned may have [some gotchas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) in this case, depending on the use case.

```
OVERLAPPED async_data = { 0 };
async_data.hEvent = event_handle;

if (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, dwIoControlCode, lpInBuffer, nInBufferSize, lpOutBuffer, nOutBufferSize, lpBytesReturned, &async_data)
{
     // do stuff, more deviceiocontrol if you want
     WaitForSingleObjects(async_data.hEvent, INFINITE);
     // We wait until it finishes
}    
// Handle error
```